# Filtration in product page shopify

Tags: shopify

Right now filtration by tag is done by `AND`.. 
(mysite.com/collections/product_sub/`x`+`y`)

what should i do so that filtration is done by `OR` i.e suppose

product `A` has tag `x`

product `B` has tag `y`

product `C` has tag `z`

now if user select `x` and `y` tags then all product should be shown having `any of both tag`

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible in shopify. Shopify will only display the products that has both x and y tags. It will not combine results.

If you want to really achieve this, You need to use ajax. So when someone will select `mysite.com/collections/product_sub/x` , Your ajax script will retrieve all products from that url.

When user will select another tag which makes the url like `mysite.com/collections/product_sub/x+y` , ajax script will retrieve all products from `mysite.com/collections/product_sub/y` and combine in product list ( make sure it remove duplicates if there any )